# Why `std::unordered_map::erase(key_type const&)` return number of removed elements?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Recently I went to use `std::unordered_map::erase`, and see the function has some overloads:

- <sub>[Link to cppreferences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase)</sub>

```cpp
iterator erase( const_iterator pos );                         (1)  (since C++11)
iterator erase( iterator pos );                               (1)  (since C++17)
iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );  (2)  (since C++11)
size_type erase( const key_type& key );                       (3)  (since C++11)
```

And in the description of the functions return value mentioned:

```sh
Return value
1-2) Iterator following the last removed element.
3) Number of elements removed.
```

The last one (3), saying we could have the number of removed elements. Does that mean it's possible to have the same keys on the map?

Comment: Also see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/erase

Comment: @MooingDuck A multimap can definitely have multiple equivalent keys though.

Comment: indeed (which is related to the answer of this question)

Comment: @Ghasem Ramezani It means that there is unordered_multimap that has a similar function. So their behavior is identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there is also `unordered_multimap` where several elements can have the same key. Returning the number of erased elements makes perfect sense for multimap, multiset, unordered_multimap and unordered_multiset. The returning of the number of elements rather than just `bool` for the non-multi containers is a way to make the common "interface" of map and multimap (etc) as close to each other as possible so that in some situations either can be used via a template parameter.
Erase for a non-multi map or set (or unordered_map or unordered_set) will indeed only ever return 0 or 1.